# PayPal Rest API for Asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, paypal

I am creating paypal rest api by the following steps 
1. created login id by developer.paypal.com
2. clicked My apps 
3. clicked button "Create app" created testapp
4. By clicking testapp I have gotted two api credentials (i) Test Credentials (ii) Live credentials (By click on show)

I am having problem by above api (Client ID and Secret ) in my code 
the code giving error no 401 or some time 400

I have checked "Account eligibility"

PayPal payments and 
Log In with PayPal is showing right sign

But
Features that are not enabled for live transactions

Direct credit cards
showing :
Note: Live credentials are disabled for direct credit card processing in your app. We are processing your information and will email you when live API credentials are enabled.

and same

Future Payments 
Note: Live credentials are disabled for future payment processing in your app. We are processing your information and will email you when live API credentials are enabled.

But If I am using other Client ID and Secret then my code is working fine.
What am I doing wrong ?
Please help me .....

Comment: Can you post some example code?

Answer (score 0):

The REST API supports [a number of countries and currencies](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/rest_api_payment_country_currency_support/). To check REST API support for direct credit card payments for a US account, see the [Account eligibility page](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/account/status). Direct credit card support in the REST API is available in the UK if you sign up for a [UK Website Payments Pro account](https://www.paypal.com/uk/webapps/mpp/pro).

If you are in the US, please visit the [Account eligibility page](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/account/status) to apply for permissions for Direct Credit cards and Future Payments. These applications are required to be reviewed and approved.